# How to split the string after dot and print it to next line

Tags: java, string

```
String string = "This is a example.just to verify.please help me."; 
if(string.matches("(.*).(.*)"))
{
  System.out.println(true); 
  String[] parts = string.split("\\r?\\n");
    for(String part:parts){
       System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```

I want to split the string after every dot to the next line. can anyone help me in this. thanks in advance.

Comment: `.` is a meta-character in regex. You should escape it using `\\.`

Comment: What is the purpose of `matches("(.*).(.*)")`? Is it supposed to be like an expensive version of `indexOf('.') != -1`?

Comment: you may use string.contains like `string.contains(".")`

Comment: @Andreas `matches("(.*).(.*)")` is true for every string but an empty one. `matches("(.*)\\.(.*)")` would be correct and a slightly more expensive version of `indexOf('.') != -1` or `indexOf('.') > -1` or `indexOf(".") > -1` or `contains(".")`. However, I go with @Avinash Raj that `contains(".")` is the most readable version. And `split("\\.")` as in the answer of @ankur-singhal does the splitting job.

Answer (score 2):

Use positive lookbehind. And also in matches function, you need to escape the dot like `string.matches(".*\\..*")`, since dot is a regex special character which matches any character.

```
String[] parts = string.split("(?<=\\.)");
```

or

If you don't want to do a split after the last dot.

```
String[] parts = string.split("(?<=\\.)(?!$)");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iI2sY4/1)

Comment: If you're fixing the `matches`, why leave the `()` in there? Why use regex? `contains(".")` is more understandable, and `indexOf('.') != -1` is the fastest.

Comment: @Andreas ya, i already mentioned `contains` in the comment. And i altered the matches part, so that he won't do the same mistake in future.

Answer (score 2):

use regex `"\\."`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "This is a example.just to verify.please help me.";
        if (string.matches("(.*).(.*)")) {
            System.out.println(true);
            String[] parts = string.split("\\.");
            for (String part : parts) {
                System.out.println(part);
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
true
This is a example
just to verify
please help me
```

Comment: `I want to split the string after every dot`, but it removes the dot.. Don't know how you receive 2 upvotes, since `string.matches("(.*).(.*)")` is wrong.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP question is simple `I want to split the string after every dot to the next line. can anyone help me in this. thanks in advance.`, also he just wanted to know how to split using `dot`

Comment: @ankur-singhal Yes, but `string.matches("(.*).(.*)")` matches every string but an empty one, if a regex should be used here `string.matches("(.*)\\.(.*)")` was correct.